# MSCHART with a transparent background

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

Any whay to make the background transparent of the MSCHART?
thank's

Comment: Doesn't this help – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070395/microsoft-charts-transparency? The part `BackColor = Color.Transparent` exactly.

Comment: well thanks for your quick answer, but this does not solve my problem, I'v alreay try it, and I do not get what i want, When I make it transparent I got a gray BG
I'm using a pie chart

Comment: Gray is a strong hint that it is working.  Give the form a different BackColor.

Comment: well I gerate this with code 
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chrt = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the Chart background colour AND the ChartArea  colour.

```
Chart c = new Chart();

c.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

c.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("ChartArea1"));
c.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help you

in your .aspx file where your chart code is, look for the asp:ChartArea tag. then add BackColor = "Transparent".

```
<asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackColor="Transparent" 
            </asp:ChartArea>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me, `HolesChart` is the name of my Chart

```
HolesChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```