# How can I make background of chart grid area transparent and axis point font colour white in C#.?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I want to create a chart in Windows form. Screen shot is attached. I want to make this white area transparent and point font colour white.
[image: Here is the screenshot of the chart]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete grid lines from Chart in WindowsForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871287/how-to-delete-grid-lines-from-chart-in-windowsform)

Comment: See this for the axis labels color: [how can I change forecolor of a chart label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822762/how-can-i-change-forecolor-of-a-chart-label)

Comment: And, in case, if you really want to make your chart area transparent: [MSCHART with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633688/mschart-with-a-transparent-background)